# PushViewController & set navigation bar color and title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I made a push function in a button:

```
@IBAction func prodButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var secondViewController = CollectionViewController()

    secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CollectionViewController") as! CollectionViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

This button pushes to the secondViewController but when I looked at the navigation bar of the second view controller I noticed that it has set up a back button automatically. The problem is that this back button's color is light blue and it doesn't fit with my design. I tried to change it like that in viewDidAppear

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()`

and also the bar color:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 65, green: 61, blue: 116, alpha: 1.0)`

but there wasn't any change.

I'd be really thankful if somebody help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your color one time, it will be the same color for everywhere after:

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
navBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

You should put this code in AppDelegate. You could also set the barTint in Storyboard if you use it.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Your are setting this line in the secondViewController right ?

Comment: Yep, in the viewDidAppear

Comment: Yes it's seems read-only, I edited my answer and it's should works for sure :)

Comment: Thank you but now the button and the bar are both white.

Comment: Just put red color on my code, you should know your design color better than me :)

Comment: I wanted to say that it changes only the button color. The bar color itself stays default.

Comment: navBar.tintColor change only buttons color, have you retry my code ?

Comment: And how can I change the bar color and the button's text? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   //Func Alter color navigation bar
   func AlteraCorNavigationBar(Navigation:UINavigationController){
       Navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = CorTextoNavigationBar()
       //Navigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = CorPredominante()
       Navigation.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : CorTextoNavigationBar(), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Light", size: 22)!]
   }


   //func CorPredominante()->UIColor{
       //return UIColor.redColor()
       //(rgba: "#ecf0f1")
       // YOU CAN LIBRARY COLOR RGBA [HERE][1] AND USE UIColor(rgba: "#b6011a")
   //}


   func CorTextoNavigationBar()->UIColor{
       return UIColor(red: 65, green: 61, blue: 116, alpha: 1.0) 
   }
```

for called in view controller:

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          AlteraCorNavigationBar(navigationController)
      }

}
```

Comment: I have no idea why but when I type `UIColor(red: 65, green: 61, blue: 116, alpha: 1.0)` the color is white. When I tell the exact color `UIColor.redColor()` it works without any problem.

Comment: Use this:  navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 65, green: 61, blue: 116, alpha: 1.0)
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: 65, green: 61, blue: 116, alpha: 1.0), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "ArialHebrew-Light", size: 22)!]

Comment: Thanks. This changes only the back button to white, the bar remains default. Do you know how can I change the button text from "Back" to something else?

Comment: This changes the back button and the title.

Comment: To change the button text back , you have to go to the storyboard and click the view of navigationBar you will come back and not on who you are , and change the text in the attributes inspector in the " back button "

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake.
The colors shoud be devided by 255:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 149.0 / 255.0, green: 148.0 / 255.0, blue: 192.0 / 255.0, alpha: 0.5)

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 65.0 / 255.0, green: 61.0 / 255.0, blue: 116.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Thank you all for the help ;)